# error compiling node-sass on yarn install

Tags: node.js, gulp-sass, sylius, node-sass

I'm trying to install sylius on an ubuntu 18.04 installation with nodejs v12.18.1.
As suggested on installation guide I'm launching yarn install to compile assets and I'm stopped while Building fresh packages (node-sass version 4.1.0) with the following error:

```
error /var/www/sylius.local/node_modules/node-sass: Command failed.
...
...
/home/matteorossi/.node-gyp/12.16.2/include/node/v8config.h:328:3: note: in definition of macro ‘V8_DEPRECATED’
...
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h: In static member function ‘static void Nan::ObjectWrap::WeakCallback(const v8::WeakCallbackInfo<Nan::ObjectWrap>&)’:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:124:26: error: ‘class Nan::Persistent<v8::Object>’ has no member named ‘IsNearDeath’
...
```

So I don't understand if such error is a sylius, a gulp-sass or nodejs related one.
Any suggestion?

Comment: try to delete your node_modules then install latest node-sass

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/11358

You have a few options:

1. Upgrade node-sass to 4.12+
2. Downgrade to a [NodeJS version supported](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#supported-nodejs-versions-vary-by-release-please-consult-the-releases-page-below-is-a-quick-guide-for-minimum-support) by your current version of node-sass
3. Use a Docker container with the supported NodeJS version to install and build assets:
   `docker run -it --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app --name node node:6-alpine yarn install`